# XIB file missing - unable to locate it

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I was clicking CTRL + Z and all of a sudden my xib file is gone. Its there but when i click it the Interface doesn't appear. How can i get this back on the IDE. Help :'(

When i click on objects its Empty. Help

Comment: I don't think we can help you, without more information. Create another project, and import your current source code.

Comment: Well, the xib file is there, when i click on it, it doesn't show up with the content (label, etc)

Comment: did you try clicking shift + cmd + Z to undo the undoing?

Comment: Yes, but i solved it. I had a partial backup file. I re-designed the missing ui components :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you didn't close the xCode you can undo the undoing by press shif+command+z .. otherwise am afraid you should add the controls again.

Answer (score 1):

A xib file is text file.  If you were undoing a lot you could very well have lost your changes. If you can no longer redo and then the data is really lost. But open the xib file and take a look. It's possible that the data is there but the files messed up somehow. That we might be able to help with. But I suspect you undid your changes and they are gone.

Answer (score 0):

Is possible that the XCode take the only nib reference away,
 you could see at folder if xib is there, if not you need add it again from zero